# phpMyAdmin errors (count, blowfish, etc.) after php7.2 upgrade on Ubuntu 16

Tags: count, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04, blowfish, php-7.2

### phpMyAdmin errors after php7.2 upgrade

After upgrading to php7.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, phpMyAdmin shows annoying popup warnings when I view tables:

> "Some errors have been detected on the server! Please look at the bottom of this window. Ignore All. Ignore."

At the bottom of the window:

> "**Warning** in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#601
>
> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

... followed by a long backtrace list.

This problem occurs on various phpMyAdmin 4.x versions including and below 4.5.4.

How do I fix this?

---

### Update - Blowfish error

After upgrading to the newest version of phpMyAdmin (4.7.9), I now get a new error that shows up at the bottom of every page:

> "The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret)."

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Manually update phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu

As of writing this, the phpMyAdmin version available in the Ubuntu [package manager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=phpmyadmin) (4.5.4) does not fully support php7.2, which leads to the annoying count() warning. **The solution is to update to the latest phpMyAdmin version**, which is 4.7.9 at the time of writing.

The Ubuntu package is behind. There is a [phpMyAdmin PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin), but it too is behind:

> “Note: This repository is currently a bit behind as I struggle to find time to update it to 4.7 series.”

Fortunately, we can manually upgrade from the older version.

**The basic steps are:**

1. Make a backup copy of current installation
2. Download and extract the latest version of phpMyAdmin
3. Modify the vendor_config.php file to the appropriate directory for Ubuntu
4. Add a longer random string to resolve blowfish error messages and allow proper cookie authentication

These terminal commands should get the job done (use sudo if applicable):

```
mv /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin_old
mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin
mkdir /var/downloads
cd /var/downloads
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.7.9/phpMyAdmin-4.7.9-all-languages.tar.gz
tar -xf phpMyAdmin-4.7.9-all-languages.tar.gz -C /usr/share/phpmyadmin --strip-components=1
```

(*Optional*) Replace the wget line with the latest version or preferred format of your choice. Visit https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/.

---

### Solve the blowfish error message

***At this point, you will probably get a blowfish error when you use phpMyAdmin***. To resolve this, you should update a specific configuration file:

1. Open `vendor_config.php` in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/vendor_config.php`
2. On or around line 38, replace `define('CONFIG_DIR', '');` with `define('CONFIG_DIR', '/etc/phpmyadmin/');` and save the file.

When you are done, lines 33-38 of `vendor_config.php` should look something like:

```
/**
 * Directory where configuration files are stored.
 * It is not used directly in code, just a convenient
 * define used further in this file.
 */
define('CONFIG_DIR', '/etc/phpmyadmin/');
```

At this point, phpMyAdmin may work without errors, ***but you might need to add additional length to the blowfish_secret configuration string***.

1. Open the file `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/blowfish_secret.inc.php`.

You should see:

```
<?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'Something Short';
```

2. Add additional randomness to the `$cfg['blowfish_secret']` string, at least 40 characters and even longer might be better (I use a string as long as 100 characters).

For example (don't use this, just an example):

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'A much longer random string 7NfSjYezwmwGCfGDuDO7uWn4ESw2sCFCym1RatPjGCfGCym1RatPjGCfG';
```

3. Save the file.

***At this point, refresh phpMyAdmin (in your browser) and login again***. Everything should work properly now.

If desired, you may remove the backup copy of the old phpMyAdmin version with:

```
rm -rfv /usr/share/phpmyadmin_old
```

---

**Additional Documentation**

For reference, the following are excerpts from the [official phpMyAdmin documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#upgrading-from-an-older-version) about manually updating to the latest version (this is *not* Ubuntu specific):

> **Warning**
>
> Never extract the new version over an existing installation of
>   phpMyAdmin, always first remove the old files keeping just the
>   configuration.
>
> This way you will not leave old no longer working code in the
>   directory, which can have severe security implications or can cause
>   various breakages.

And:

> The complete upgrade can be performed in few simple steps:
>
> 1. Download the latest phpMyAdmin version from
>      https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/.
> 2. Rename existing phpMyAdmin folder (for example to phpmyadmin-old).
> 3. Unpack freshly donwloaded phpMyAdmin to desired location (for example phpmyadmin).
> 4. Copy config.inc.php` from old location (phpmyadmin-old) to new one (phpmyadmin).
> 5. Test that everything works properly.
> 6. Remove backup of previous version (phpmyadmin-old).

Comment: +1 incredibly thorough and worked great, wish I could give another +1 for the command line shortcuts! I didn't get a Blowfish error, so that was even easier  (I am using Laravel Homestead, so I had to change /usr/share/ to /Code/)

Comment: On Debian 9.6 + Nginx, I had to chown: `chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 0):

Your other option to fix the errors is to temporarily downgrade php to version 7.1, until ubuntu catches up on its version of phpmyadmin.  Instructions [here](https://websiteforstudents.com/downgrade-php-7-2-to-php-7-1-with-apache2-http-server-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/). I found this easier, and have no reason to be on the bleeding edge of php anyway.