# Mysql Dump : count() Parameter must be an array of an object that implements countable

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

`Mysql error:`    Backtrace ./libraries/display_export.lib.php#380: PMA_pluginGetOptions( string 'Export', array, ) ./libraries/display_export.lib.php#883: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptionsFormat(array) ./libraries/display_export.inc.php#74: PMA_getHtmlForExportOptions( string 'server',

string '', string '', string 'Select all / Unselect all
 my_database my_database phpmyadmin ', string '', array, string '', ) ./server_export.php#30: require_once(./libraries/display_export.inc.php)[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin errors (count, blowfish, etc.) after php7.2 upgrade on Ubuntu 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246107/phpmyadmin-errors-count-blowfish-etc-after-php7-2-upgrade-on-ubuntu-16)

Comment: What are you trying to do when the error occurs? Which phpMyAdmin and PHP versions do you have?

Answer (score 0):

> phpmyadmin’s library try to count some parameter. At this line 532, I
>   found this code in this path

**file name : $ /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php**

**Find this line :**

if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {

**Replace with :**

if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {

> It can’t use count() or sizeof() with un array type. Force parameter
>   to array is easy way to solve this bug