# after installing phpmyadmin, have problems with errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

PHP version: 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
phpMyAdmin 4.6.6

On my Install of Phpmyadmin, I get two errors when opening it. One under import and one under export!  Is this because mysql-server is wrong or is it because of fault in phpmyadmin? and how do I take care of it?
I installed it on Debian9 and had no problem!

Under Export:

> Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551
>   count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
>   Backtrace

Under Import I get:

```
Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
Backtrace
./libraries/display_import.lib.php#371: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Import',
array,
)
./libraries/display_export.lib.php#381: PMA_pluginGetOptions(
string 'Export',
array,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on the same trio of Ubuntu, php, and phpmyadmin versions.

The problem is that phpmyadmin at 4.6.6 has minor incompatibilities with PHP version 7.2.19. These are solved by updating to version 4.7.9 of phpMyAdmin.

As noted in another answer, the basic steps are:

1. Make a backup copy of your current installation in /usr/share/phpmyadmin
2. Download and extract the latest version of phpMyAdmin
3. Modify the vendor_config.php file to point at the appropriate directory for Ubuntu, /etc/phpmyadmin

```
    mv /usr/share/phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin_old
    mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    mkdir /var/downloads
    cd /var/downloads
    wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.7.9/phpMyAdmin-4.7.9-all-languages.tar.gz
    tar -xf phpMyAdmin-4.7.9-all-languages.tar.gz -C /usr/share/phpmyadmin --strip-components=1
```

My answer is a copy of the same solution for Ubuntu 16 as provided in [phpMyAdmin errors (count, blowfish, etc.) after php7.2 upgrade on Ubuntu 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246107/phpmyadmin-errors-count-blowfish-etc-after-php7-2-upgrade-on-ubuntu-16)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @coreuter Thanks for your advice. I edited my answer per your suggestion.